# Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT with parameters

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to run the following on ENTRYPOINT[..]:

```
dotnet reportgenerator -reports:coverage.cobertura.xml -targetdir:Reports -reportTypes:htmlInline
```

How do I do this?

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [execform](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) of `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","reportgenerator","-reports:coverage.cobertura.xml","-targetdir:Reports","-reportTypes:htmlInline"]
```

Apart from `execform` there is the shell form, which looks like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT command param1 param2
```

In the `ENTRYPOINT` array, you should include stable default(they are not considered changeable) commands with their arguments. Then if you wish to set additional defaults that are more likely to be changed use `CMD`.

Example taken from the official's documentation link:

```
FROM ubuntu
ENTRYPOINT ["top", "-b"]
CMD ["-c"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try?

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "reportgenerator", "-reports:coverage.cobertura.xml", "-targetdir:Reports", "-reportTypes:htmlInline"]
```

Comment: Yes, this works.  I must have tried everything else under the sun.  Still don't quite understand how ENTRYPOINT works.